# Aligning entries in nested grid layouts in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid-layout

I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI(Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    self.frame = Frame(self)
    self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    row = 0
    self.source_lbl = Label(self.frame, text="Source:")
    self.source_lbl.grid(column=0, row=row, sticky='w')
    self.source_txt = Entry(self.frame, width=60)
    self.source_txt.grid(column=1, row=row)
    self.source_btn = Button(self.frame, text="Browse")
    self.source_btn.grid(column=2, row=row)

    row += 1
    self.extra_frame = ExtraFrame(self.frame)
    self.extra_frame.grid(row=row, columnspan=3, sticky='w')


class ExtraFrame(Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super().__init__(*args, **kw)
    self.pairs = []

    self.key_lbl = Label(self, text="Key", anchor='w')
    self.value_lbl = Label(self, text="Value", anchor='w')

    self.add_btn = Button(self, text="+", command=self.add_pair)
    self.add_btn.grid()

  def add_pair(self):
    pair_frame = KWFrame(self, pady=2)
    self.pairs.append(pair_frame)
    pair_frame.grid(row=len(self.pairs), columnspan=3)
    self.update_labels_and_button()

  def update_labels_and_button(self):
    if self.pairs:
      self.key_lbl.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
      self.value_lbl.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='w')
    else:
      self.key_lbl.grid_remove()
      self.value_lbl.grid_remove()
    self.add_btn.grid(row=len(self.pairs) + 1)


class KWFrame(Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    self.key_txt = Entry(self, width=30)
    self.key_txt.grid(column=0, row=0)

    self.value_txt = Entry(self, width=30)
    self.value_txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

    self.remove_btn = Button(self, text="-", command=self.remove)
    self.remove_btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

  def remove(self):
    i = self.master.pairs.index(self)
    del self.master.pairs[i]
    for pair in self.master.pairs[i:]:
      pair.grid(row=pair.grid_info()['row'] - 1)
    self.master.update_labels_and_button()
    self.destroy()

gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

This works nicely with being able to add/remove new text entry rows, with only one problem: the labels "Key" and "Value" aren't aligned with their respective entry fields in those rows (despite having the correct column values). Is there a simple way to align them nicely using such a nested grid layout?

Comment: `Label(... , width=30)` - not ideal but works.

Comment: Not the cleanest, but I'll take it.

Comment: Add `self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) ; self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` to both `class ExtraFrame` and `class KWFrame` and use `sticky='ew'`